# Deploy to onpremise servers, SSIS, Azure Devops

Tags: ssis, azure-devops

I'm using Azure Devops and want to setup CD.

I have registered my onpremise server using the PowerShell script. The appear in Azure Devops as "ONLINE". However, when I try to deploy using a release with the "Microsoft SSIS Build task", I get an error indicating that it can't reach the server. The server is online.

Any advice? What am I doing wrong?

2020-05-16T10:49:17.3274679Z Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException: Failed to connect to server psjtst*****. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found
2020-05-16T10:49:17.3276924Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2020-05-16T10:49:17.3278587Z    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
2020-05-16T10:49:17.3282547Z    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're adding a release pipeline, there are diferent types of agent jobs. This is what I overlooked. I needed to use a "deployment group job" in order to have line of sight to my onpremise servers.

Answer (score 1):

**SSIS Build task relies on** Visual Studio and **SSIS designer**, which is mandatory on build agents. Thus, to run SSIS Build task in the pipeline, you must choose vs2017-win2016 for Microsoft-hosted agents, or **install Visual Studio and SSIS designer (either VS2017 + SSDT2017, or VS2019 + SSIS Projects extension) on self-hosted agents.**

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.*

According to the error info, please make sure your build agent do not have these [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations-and-known-issues).

Besides, since you are using self-host agent, please also make sure your build service account  could remote access your on-premise server and have enough permission.

Better add that account as local Admin and SQL Server Admin on your on-premise server.